# Matlab: Explicit or named association of `splitapply` arguments with table VariableNames

Tags: sql, matlab

I've been biting the bullet on the extra code and bookkeeping needed in Matlab to perform common SQL operations.  Here is an example of a typical SQL code pattern for generating metrics that summarize a data table `tDat`:

```
SELECT vGrouping, MEAN( x - y ) AS rollup1, VAR(y+z) AS rollup2
INTO tRollups FROM tDat GROUP BY vGrouping
```

My SQL's a bit rusty, but the general idea should be clear to SQLers.  Here is the Matlab equivalent:

```
% Create test data
tDat = array2table( floor(10*rand(5,3)) , ...
                    'VariableNames',{'x','y','z'} );
tDat.vGrouping = ( rand(5,1) > 0.5 )

% Calculate summary metrics for each group of data
[vGroup,grps] = findgroups(tDat.vGrouping)
fRollup = @(a,b,c)[ mean(a-b) var(b+c) ] % Calculates summary metric
rollups = splitapply( fRollup, tDat(:,{'x','y','z'}), vGroup )

% Code pattern 1 to assemble results
tRollups = [ array2table( grps , 'VariableNames',{'group'} ) ...
             array2table( rollups , ...
                          'VariableNames',{'rollup1','rollup2'} ) ]

% Code pattern 2 to assemble results
tRollups = array2table( [grps rollups], ...
                        'VariableNames',{'group','rollup1','rollup2'} )
```

It's not a fair comparison because the Matlab code contains the data setup, as well as two possible code patterns for assembling the summary metrics.  Furthermore, I've added comments -- not to make the Matlab code more voluminous, but because it is so much busier that some cognitive signposts are needed to aid in the reading.

Code volume aside, however, one of the things that bugs me is that the rollup expressions in `fRollup` are not explicitly associated with the names of the input or output data columns.  The arguments are dummy arguments, and the actual input data columns from `tDat` are specified in the `splitapply` invocation.  The association with the fRollup arguments are positional, so field/variable names themselves aren't able to enforce correct association.  Likewise, the output columns in tRollups are specified in the array2table invocation, again positionally associated with the `fRollup` output.

This makes the rather simple relationships in the SQL statement very difficult to see in the Matlab code.  Is there an alternate pattern or design idiom that doesn't have this drawback, but hopefully, doesn't incur much in the way of other drawbacks?

**AFTERNOTE:** For some reason, even though the following doesn't solve the named/explicit association of `splitapply` input/output arguments with actual input/output variables, I still find it easier to see the relationships.  The code definitely looks less noisier.  The key is that the function `fRollup` for generating summary metrics on the data now returns multiple outputs instead of bundling them into a single arrayed output.  This allows me to explicitly name properties of scalar `struct` `ssRollups` as the target of the assignment.  I don't need to all sorts of conversions to tables, with the extra code to designate `VariableNames`, just to concatenate the results with the identified groups.  Instead, the group identities *start off* as just another property `grps` in the same `struct` (`ssRollups`) as the `splitapply` results -- in fact, it is the first property that brings the `struct` into existence.

```
% File tmp.m
%-----------
function tmp

   % Create test data
   tDat = array2table( floor(10*rand(5,3)) , ...
                       'VariableNames',{'x','y','z'} );
   tDat.vGrouping = ( rand(5,1) > 0.5 )

   % Find the groups
   [ vGroup, ssRollups.grps ] = findgroups(tDat.vGrouping)

   % Calculate summary metrics for each group of data
   [ ssRollups.rollup1 ssRollups.rollup2 ] = ...
      splitapply( @fRollup, tDat(:,{'x','y','z'}), vGroup );

   % Display use nice table formatting
   struct2table( ssRollups )

end % function tmp

function [rollup1 rollup2] = fRollup(a,b,c)
   rollup1 = mean(a-b);
   rollup2 = var(b+c);
end % function fRollup
```

As a multiple-output function, however, `fRollup` seems better suited to a non-anonymous function.  To me, it actually seems to document the multiple outputs better, despite the less compact code.  It may be just one of those situations where more compactness is less readable, causing the data relationships to be harder to see.  However, it does require that the entire passage of code be made into a function (`tmp` in this case), unless you don't mind breaking out `fRollup` into it's own function and m-file. I prefer not to litter my file system with such tiny snippet functions meant to be used in one place.

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at the groupsummary function, but if you require non-standard indicators to be calculated I fear this cannot fit your needs.

Comment: I think you're right, I'm SOL.  The group summary function illustrated here is only an example.  I'm looking for a general approach that will make the relationships easier to see.  Furthermore, `doc groupsummary` does not yield anything in my Matlab 2015b.  I found the help page on the web, but it doesn't specify the version in which it made its debut.  Funny, I seem to recall Matlab documentation providing that info.

Comment: You find it at the bottom of the doc page `Introduced in R2018a`

Comment: Doh!  How was it possible to miss that, especially since I was looking around the bottom area for it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "answer" doesn't directly deal with explicit named association between the actual input/output variables and the arguments of the function handle supplied to `splitapply`.  However, it significantly simplifies the code in the initial example, hopefully making it clearer to see the relationship between the function arguments and the input/output variables.  This solution was initially included in the **AFTERNOTE** in the question.  Since better answers don't appear to be forthcoming soon, I've decided to hive it out as the answer.  It uses `deal` to implement an anonymous multiple-output function for `splitapply` to use on the data groups that are delineated by its grouping argument.

```
% Create test data
tDat = array2table( floor(10*rand(5,3)) , ...
                    'VariableNames',{'x','y','z'} );
tDat.vGrouping = ( rand(5,1) > 0.5 )

% Find the groups
[ vGroup, ssRollups.grps ] = findgroups(tDat.vGrouping)

% Calculate summary metrics for each group of data
fRollup = @(a,b,c) deal( mean(a-b), var(b+c) )
[ ssRollups.rollup1 ssRollups.rollup2 ] = ...
   splitapply( fRollup, tDat(:,{'x','y','z'}), vGroup );

% Display use nice table formatting
struct2table( ssRollups )
```

Until a better solution emerges, this approach will be my go-to idiom for `splitapply`.

Here is a variation that uses a table variable for the output of `splitapply`.  This might be more convenient when using multiple grouping variables because `findgroups` will pass the grouping variable names to the output variable `tRollups` on the LHS:

```
% Create test data
tDat = array2table( floor(10*rand(8,3)) , ...
                    'VariableNames',{'x','y','z'} );
tDat = [ tDat ...
         array2table( rand(8,2)>0.5 , ...
                      'VariableNames',{'vGrpng1','vGrpng2'} ) ];

% Find the groups
[ vGroup, tRollups ] = findgroups(tDat(:,{'vGrpng1','vGrpng2'}));

% Calculate summary metrics for each group of data
fRollup = @(a,b,c) deal( mean(a-b), var(b+c) )
[ tRollups.rollup1 tRollups.rollup2 ] = ...
   splitapply( fRollup, tDat(:,{'x','y','z'}), vGroup );

tRollups
```

And here is a version that uses multiple grouping variables and uses a scalar struct instead of a table for the outputs of `findgroup` and `splitapply`:

```
% Create test data
tDat = array2table( floor(10*rand(8,3)) , ...
                    'VariableNames',{'x','y','z'} );
tDat.vGrpng1 = rand(8,1)>0.5 ;
tDat.vGrpng2 = rand(8,1)>0.5

% Find the groups
[ vGroup, ssRollups.vGrpng1, ssRollups.vGrpng2 ] = ...
    findgroups( tDat.vGrpng1, tDat.vGrpng2 );

% Calculate summary metrics for each group of data
fRollup = @(a,b,c) deal( mean(a-b), var(b+c) )
[ ssRollups.rollup1 ssRollups.rollup2 ] = ...
   splitapply( fRollup, tDat(:,{'x','y','z'}), vGroup );

% Display using nice table formatting
struct2table( ssRollups )
```